# can't get height set in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in the footer, so when all content loads. The alert gives the correct result but when I apply that same var to the height of the #'container doens't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var original_height = $("#container").height();
    var newDistance = $(".detta .content").outerHeight(true);
    var total = original_height + newDistance;
    alert(total);
    $(".detta .box").animate({top: newDistance});
    $("#container").height(total);
});
```

container doens't have any set height in the css.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your code into a `$(function(){...});`   ready function ?

Comment: sound't be the need no? it's in the footer after all content.. or does it still need it?

Comment: It depends if your container is loading images for example.

Comment: just tried tho, nothing changes. I dont understand, screngrab gives height 419 in photoshop but alert say 589, don't get it

Comment: it is actually loading images and also video from vimeo... updated the question using .ready, i get the same result tho

Comment: @rob.m What *exactly* is the "result"?  After that code runs, do you check the element with Firebug or some other debugger to see what it's effective style settings are?

Comment: yes it's like it is not applying the height, check the live example, red border is the container, see? it's not actually getting the new height i'm assigning in the code and it's cutting the boxes: (above code is at the footer) http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/directors-4/regista/marco-missano/

Comment: answered my own quest, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
    var original_height = $("#container").height();
    var newDistance = $(".detta .content").outerHeight(true);
    var total = original_height + newDistance;
    $(".detta .box").animate({top: newDistance}, function(){
        $("#container").height(total);
    });
 });
```

bingo! the new container height had to be triggered, so i just apply it after box animation happens

Answer (score 0):

Instead this :

```
 $("#container").height(total);
```

try this :

```
 $("#container").css("height",total);
```

Good- Luck !

Comment: This should make no difference at all.